# Why do we write this tensor notation of space-time gradient contravariant tensor?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, notation, covariance

Why is $\partial^\mu=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\mu}}$ the contravariant component of space-time gradient four vector instad of $\partial^{\mu}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}}$?

Comment: We use index position to indicate how parts of objects transform under changes of coordinates. The position $x^\mu$ is the component of a position vector, and changes contravariantly to the basis vectors, and thus has an upper index. The derivative is normally defined with respect to this contravariant position, and one can show that $\frac{∂}{∂ x^\mu}$ will transform co-variantly and thus we mark it in condensed notation with a lower index: $∂_\mu$

Comment: please share a link where this transform showing @Craig

Comment: Try it yourself: if $X=x^\mu e_\mu$ is a position vector in Euclidean cartesian coordinates, and you double the length of your basis vectors, what must happen to your components in order to describe the same vector? How does this change in the components carry over through your derivative operator?

Comment: @Craig: That should be an answer.

Comment: Sometimes you can just let the notation guide you. In your proposed definition it would be $\partial_\mu x^2 = 2 x^\mu$ and in the standard one $\partial_\mu x^2 = 2 x_\mu$. In any equality the indices in the two sides must be at the same height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will elaborate a bit on the comment and fill in the explicit computation:
A vector $a \in V$ can be written as $a=a^\mu e_\mu$. Under a transformation to a new basis:
\begin{align}
 \bar{e}_\mu = \Lambda_\mu {}^{\nu} e_\nu
\end{align}
its components transform linearly with:
\begin{align}
\bar{a}^\mu = \Lambda^\mu {}_\nu a^\nu .
\end{align}
Of course, the vector stays invariant (its components and the basis do not!):
\begin{align}
a= \bar{a}^\mu \bar{e}_\mu= \Lambda^\mu {}_\nu  \Lambda_\mu {}^{\rho} a^\nu e_\rho=a^\nu e_\nu
\end{align}
and therefore:
\begin{align}
\Lambda^\mu {}_\nu \Lambda_\mu {}^\rho=\delta_\nu^\rho . \tag{$\star$}
\end{align}

Now to your question:
We have established the transformation of the components: $\bar{x}^\mu = \Lambda^\mu {}_\nu x^\nu$ giving us:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}= \Lambda^\mu {}_\sigma \frac{\partial x^\sigma}{\partial x^\nu}=\Lambda^\mu {}_\sigma \delta_\nu^\sigma=\Lambda^\mu {}_\nu . \tag{$\star \star$}
\end{align} 
Furthermore:
\begin{align}
\delta^\mu_\sigma=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma}=\frac{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^\nu}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma}\stackrel{(\star \star)}{=}\Lambda^\mu {}_\nu \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma}  .
\end{align}
Comparing with $(\star)$ yields:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\sigma}=\Lambda_\sigma{}^\nu . \tag{$\star \star \star$}
\end{align}
Now we look to answer your question:
\begin{align}
\bar{\partial}_\mu:= \frac{\partial}{\partial \bar{x}^\mu }=\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial \bar{x}^\mu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\nu}\stackrel{(\star \star \star)}{=} \Lambda_\mu {}^\nu \partial_\nu .
\end{align}
As you can see the gradient of a scalar field $\partial_\mu f$ transforms as a covariant vector field. However, I did not show it for the derivative you asked for on purpose, so that you can try to get familiar with these kind of computation by repeating all the steps.